# How to wait for a function to finish

Tags: angular, typescript

I want a function `this.refresh()` to start only after the function `this.getAuthorizedDatabases()` is finished.
Do you have any ideas on how to do that easily ?

Thank you in advance.

```
  ngOnInit() {
      this.userService.currentUser
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.user = res;
        this.getAuthorizedDatabases();

      });
     this.refresh();
  }
```

Comment: It depends if `getAuthorizedDatabases` is synchronous or asynchronous. What does it actually do?

Answer (score 0):

Unless `getAuthorizedDatabases()` is also asynchronous you can do

```
   ngOnInit() {
          this.userService.currentUser
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.user = res;
            this.getAuthorizedDatabases();
            this.refresh();
          });
```

Observables are asynchronous and execution will not wait for the Observable to finish.

Answer (score 0):

If `getAuthorizedDatabases()` is synchronous.

```js
 ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.currentUser
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.user = res;
            this.getAuthorizedDatabases();
            this.refresh();
        });
}
```

If `getAuthorizedDatabases()` is asynchronous. using [Async-await](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/using-async-await-feature-in-angular-587dd56fdc77)

```js
 async ngOnInit() {
    this.userService.currentUser
        .subscribe(res => {
            this.user = res;
            await this.getAuthorizedDatabases();
            this.refresh();
        });
}
```